# RTABmap with ROS2 & gazebo simulated camera

Tags: gazebo, rviz, rtabmap, depth-image

[image: Rviz/rtabmap, flat pointcloud]

Hey guys,

I'm trying to simulated a test setup with gazebo. I have a depth camera, rgbd_cammera added to my model and bridged the topics: color/image_raw, depth/image_raw, camera_info, /color/points to ROS2. In RVIZ they look alright, except the range of the depth image is off. I have to manually set max value within rviz to get a image otherwise it is just black.

Because of this(I think) Rtabmap doesn't register the depths correctly and shows me an almost flat pointcloud. Any parameters I can set so it normalizes the range of the depth images?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the calibration topic is wrong. Is the resolution set in the `camera_info` the same than the actual image? Are the fx,fy,cx,cy components make sense in P matrix? For example, cx and cy should be approximately half of the resolution width and height respectively.